# Setting separate ACLS for BigQuery and App-engine projects within the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Is there a way to have separate ACLS for different components within a project in Google Cloud console. Example, I would like to have a few of my team members have edit rights big query instance but view only access to app-engine component and vice versa. There does not seem to be a way to do this today using the google cloud console?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a way to grant rights to different users based on the components they're using, there are ACLs within the components that may be sufficient.

There are ACLs on BigQuery datasets, so you can always restrict edit rights on the dataset without changing the project ACLs. Datasets start out with the project ACL by default, but you can always remove the default entries and/or add your own.

So in the case you mentioned, if you add the members of your team that you want to have edit rights to bigquery but only read access to appengine as "can view" on the project but give them write access to yourthe BigQUery datasets, this should take care of the first case.

Likewise, to give people edit access to your appengine app but only read access to your bigquery data, you can give them edit rights on the project but remove the 'project editors' acl entry from the dataset ACL.

Does this satisfy your use case?